# Wordpress: Show trashed posts by date trashed

Tags: php, date, wordpress

I'm using this code...

```
<ul>
<?php 
$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page'  => 10,
    'orderby'         => 'post_date',
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    'post_status'     => 'publish, trash'
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php while ($query -> have_posts()) : $query -> the_post();
?>

    <li>
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        <br />Post Created on: <?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
        <br />Post Trashed on: <?php echo "???"; ?>
    </li>

<?php 
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</ul>
```

...to display a list of the most recent 10 published or trashed posts.

But regarding the trashed posts that get returned, they need to be the date the post was trashed, not when it was created.

To further illustrate the problem, If there were some posts from over a year ago, and I trashed them today, they wouldn't appear in this list because they are not amongst the most recent 10 posts in the database.

What needs to happen is that if I did trash a very old post right now, then it would appear in this list (at the top of the list in fact - because I trashed it just now).

So ultimately what this list needs to reflect is:

- Any new post that was added, showing the date the post was created.
- Any post that was trashed, showing the date the post was trashed.

Think of it like an activity log (this is ultimately what it is), showing a combination of posts recently created and posts recently trashed, with their respective published and trashed dates next to them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question asked before. Read this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159891/how-to-retrieve-the-date-on-which-a-post-was-moved-to-trash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `'orderby' => 'modified'`, when you trash a post it changes the modified date, you can also display it using `echo get_the_modified_date()`

or by using `get_posts()`

```
$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page'  => 10,
    'orderby'         => 'modified',
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    'post_status'     => 'publish, trash'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args ); 
$posts = $query->get_posts();  
foreach ( $posts as $post ) { 
    _e($post->post_title ' - Modified On:'. $post->post_modified);
}
```

Comment: Bravvo - that was simple (and obvious) actually. Thanks.